# JSON data not saved to file - PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to save some JSON data to a local file. I am making a cUrl call to a REST service and doing the following:

```
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
$handle = fopen(time().'.txt','w');
fwrite($handle, $content);
print $content;
```

The file is created, but it is empty with the exception of the numeral 1. The JSON string does print out to screen without any problems, so the issue is not that I am getting an error. Any idea why this may be happening?

## Answser:

I forgot to add the following to the curl call:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

Comment: Nothing in the error logs at all?

Comment: `fwrite() returns the number of bytes written, or FALSE on error.` - Please post the result of `fwrite`.

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: I wish they would add a rule to force users to state why they voted a question or an answer down. That would definitely cut down on the number of trolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of debugging, it would be easier to print the result until you have one and then save to file after you know you have something.

Did you set the option "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER" ?
You need to do that to use cURL the way you are.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to debug this:

- replace `$content` with a static value (e.g.: `$content = "foo";`)
- try to properly close the file by adding `fclose($handle);`
- add `error_reporting(0);` at the beginning to be sure to see any error occurring
- check the permissions

Comment: closing the file is syntactically proper, but php closes it automatically.